# @ConditionalOnMissingBean vs @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

We´re working on multi-module project where each module is a cutom spring boot starter that holds several [retryable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html) tasks. (Using [spring-retry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html))

In order to ensure that retry annotations are activated only once cross starters, a configuration bean is added to each starter auto configuration submodule:

```
 @EnableRetry
 @Configuration
 @ConditionalOnMissingBean(RetryConfiguration.class)
 public class StarterRetryAutoConfiguation {}
```

The solution is working as expected.

**Question:**  What's the difference between `@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` ?

I've read the Spring documentation more then once. However, I didn't get when and where should we use each one of them.

**ConditionalOnSingleCandidate:**

> @Conditional that only matches when a bean of the specified class is
>   already contained in the BeanFactory and a single candidate can be
>   determined. The condition will also match if multiple matching bean
>   instances are already contained in the BeanFactory but a primary
>   candidate has been defined; essentially, the condition match if
>   auto-wiring a bean with the defined type will succeed.
>
> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been
>   processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is
>   strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration
>   classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another
>   auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs
>   after.

**ConditionalOnMissingBean:**

> @Conditional that only matches when no beans meeting the specified
>   requirements are already contained in the BeanFactory. None of the
>   requirements must be met for the condition to match and the
>   requirements do not have to be met by the same bean.

Answer (score 1):

We can use @ConditionalOnMissingBean if we want to load a bean only if a certain other bean is not in the application context:

```
@Configuration
class OnMissingBeanModule {
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  DataSource dataSource() {
    return new InMemoryDataSource();
  }
}
```

In this example, **we’re only injecting an in-memory datasource into the application context if there is not already a datasource available**. This is very similar to what Spring Boot does internally to provide an in-memory database in a test context.

---

We can use @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate if we want to load a bean only if a single candidate for the given bean class has been determined.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(DataSource.class)
class OnSingleCandidateModule {
  ...
}
```

In this example, **the condition matches if there is exactly one primary DataSource bean specified in your application context**.